# Is there an additive that can lower the freezing point of jet fuel?

Tags: jet-fuel

Does an additive exist to decrease the freezing point of jet fuel? I have found an additive that decrease the freezing point generated by drops of water (appears between 0 and -10°C), but I'm needing to reduce the freezing of the fuel (-45°C).

Comment: Jet A freeze at -40 C. Jet A-1 freeze at -47 C. Maybe just switch to jet A-1?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_fuel

Comment: Isn't stuff called Prist used to prevent freezing?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_system_icing_inhibitor

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit on your use case to help us out. Jet fuel already has a pretty low freezing point and [airplanes have no problem keeping it liquid throughout a flight.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2185/how-do-aircraft-keep-fuel-from-freezing-while-in-flight) Spacecraft generally solve the issue with tank insulation which may be of interest to you.

Comment: Concur with @vasin1987, Switch to Jet A-1 and problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

There is an additive known as a Fuel System Icing Inhibitor (FSII), it is designed to be mixed with the fuel of non-fuel heated aircraft i.e military. Mixed in at about 0.10-0.15% is optimal to reduce the formation of ice crystals, which will stop it freezing.

Source: http://www.advancepetro.com/fsii.htm

Alternatively, Jet A-1 fuel has a freezing point of -47°C, which is below your threshold and could be useful. Or if Jet A-1 is unavailable you could try Jet B which has a lower freezing point of -60°C, but is more dangerous to handle, and is less prevalent and hence unavailable at many locations.

Sources: http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/20100814170713/http%3A//www.dstan.mod.uk/standards/defstans/91/091/00000600.pdf

http://www.csgnetwork.com/jetfuel.html

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Comment: anti icing is clearly a different thing. more to prevent the water content from icing, not prevent the fuel content from freezing.

Comment: It was also mentioned somewhere around here that some newer engines are not allowed to be used with Jet-B.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE. There is also JP-4 that can go down to -57°C. JP-8 is Jet A-1 plus more additives that may have better availability in the US than Jet A-1.

Answer (score 1):

Question to Wehrner von Braun: "Why did you name it Saturn?". Answer: "It was the one after Jupiter!"

The lower freezing jet fuel is Jet B.

Jet fuel (kerosene) is taken from a higher boiling fraction than "naphtha" (gasoline) when refining crude oil.  A mixture of kerosene and naphtha will lower the freezing point.  This is how Jet B is made.

Before doing this in your garage, make sure there is no water in the mix, as frozen ice crystals will be present at much higher temperatures.

Comment: Also, don't do this in your garage, as Jet B burns/explodes _much_ more enthusiastically than Jet A-1, and at much lower temperatures.